# SIPML5 and Node-Webkit - Websocket error

Tags: javascript, websocket, node-webkit

I have this error in Node-webkit: WebSocket connection to 'wss://ns313841.ovh.net:13062/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response.

But in Chrome Browser all works fine. Any idea? :/

Full JS log:

> SIPML5 API version = 1.5.222 VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36 VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> WebSocket supported = yes VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> Navigator friendly name = chrome VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> OS friendly name = windows VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> Have WebRTC = yes VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> Have GUM = yes VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> Engine initialized VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> s_websocket_server_url=(null) VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> s_sip_outboundproxy_url=udp://xxxxxxx VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> b_rtcweb_breaker_enabled=yes VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> b_click2call_enabled=no VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> b_early_ims=yes VM131 SIPml-api.js:890
>
> b_enable_media_stream_cache=no SIPml-api.js:890
>
> o_bandwidth={} SIPml-api.js:890
>
> o_video_size={} SIPml-api.js:890
>
> SIP stack start: proxy='ns313841.ovh.net:13062',
>   realm='', impi='xxxxxxx',
>   impu='"xxxxxxx"' SIPml-api.js:890
>
> Connecting to 'wss://ns313841.ovh.net:13062' SIPml-api.js:890
>
> 'starting' event fired sipml5.js:11
>
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://ns313841.ovh.net:13062/' failed:
>   Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
>   SIPml-api.js:16579
>
> __tsip_transport_ws_onerror SIPml-api.js:890
>
> __tsip_transport_ws_onclose SIPml-api.js:890
>
> 'failed_to_start' event fired

Comment: Handshake refers to TLS/SSL enryption used for secured connections so I would start digging from that direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused because node-webkit send a blank User-Agent field in its websocket request, which (in my case atleast) causes it to close the websocket.

i am using TelePresence (which relies on Doubaungo library like WebRTC2SIP)